# controlling if the number is being rounded up or down in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding

So I know how to round a number in python. It's fairly straightforward.
But I'm wondering is there a way to round a random floating point up to the next integer.
Or round it straight down.
So if there was 8.7 to have the choice to bring it down to 8.
Or if there was 8.3 to have the choice to bring it up to 9.

Because the number is a random floating point, i wont know whether it's 8.3 or 8.7 or 8.5 or 8.48237 but I always want it  to round up to 9. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be looking for [`math.ceil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil).

```
>>> from math import ceil
>>> ceil(8.3)
9.0
>>> ceil(8.48237)
9.0
```

`ceil` Function ->

```
ceil(...)
    ceil(x)

    Return the ceiling of x as a float.
    This is the smallest integral value >= x.
```